# ajax call sharepoint hosted wcf service bad request

Tags: ajax, json, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in Sharepoint 2010 (therefore no config file necessary --> ServiceHost Factory set to MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory).

My service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Course> GetAllCoursesByPerno(string empPerno);
```

My ajax call:

```
var input = $j("#perno").val();
    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/_vti_bin/Project/Service.svc/GetAllCoursesByPerno",
        dataType: "json",
        //data: input,
        data: '{"empPerno": "' + input + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var courseData = data;
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.statusText);
        }
     });
```

My method:

```
public List<Course> GetAllCoursesByPerno(string empPerno)
{
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I get a 400 Bad Request each time. I've tried every which way to compose the data;

```
data: '{"empPerno": "' + input + '"}',

data: JSON.stringify({ empPerno : input }),
```

But no cigar. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft ajax library for calling.
This also avoid DateTime deserializing issues

```
Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke('/_vti_bin/YourSubfolder/SearchService.svc',
        'EmptyMethod',
        false,
        {data: 'client data'},
        function () {
            console.log('Success', arguments);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Eroor', arguments);
        }, this);
```